# How to use Crashlytics with iOS / OS X today view extensions?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, today-extension, ios-extensions, osx-extensions

Since today extensions run as separated a process I am sure they will not log any crashes out of the box. I assume we need to initialize Crashlytics on the widget separately. E.g. in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `TodayViewController`.

- Is anybody already using Crashlytics inside any iOS / OS X extensions? If so, how did you implemented it?
- I am also wondering if it would make sense to create a separate app in Crashlytics just for the extension.

Comment: I haven't been able to use almost anything inside the extensions (Flurry does not work, crashlytics does not work, and even a .h file I have with some asssert macros does not work...)

Comment: This is a support question for Crashlytics. Please contact them directly.

Comment: @wolffan thats disappointing so far.

Comment: @Kerni as far as I know they ask people to create issues here on stackoverflow with their tag. However, I cannot find the quote anymore … so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Crashlytics support got in touch with me and provided these steps. I tested them and it now works for me iOS 8 app.

1. Add the Crashlytics Run Script Build Phase to your extension's target as well (copy / paste the same you added to your main app)
2. Add the `Crashlytics.framework` to your extension's linked libraries 
   (e.g. simply check the extension target in its file inspector)
3. Add the `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("yourApiKey")` to your extension's view controller's `initWithCoder`method. (In Apple's today extension template it is called  `TodayViewController` by default)

   *> if you have no `initWithCoder` method yet, it should look like this afterwards:*

   ```
   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("yourApiKey")
   }
   ```

Comment: Forgot to mention: Since every extensions needs to have it's own bundle id, Crashlytics create a separate app in the dashboard on its own anyway.

Comment: This fails 50% of the time for me. It may be a problem with multiple extensions (Today and Watch). Basically, I need to rebuild my project all the time because it fails due to Crashlytics not finding the dSYM about every other time.

Comment: How can it be? I do `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` inside `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, it says `[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize`

Comment: Does `Crashlytics` call `CrashlyticsDelegate` when a previous crash occurred on an app extension? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61801745/9636

Answer (score 8):

Here is Twitter's own guide to implementing it:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/integrate-fabric-crashlytics-with-ios-8-extension/28905

So, copy the libraries, for instance if you're using CocoaPods you can add Fabric and Crashlytics to the Extension target:

**In Podfile:**

```
target :TodayExtension do
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

and run `pod install`. And don't forget to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`, or you may get linker errors

Then in your TodayViewController:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

...

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
    return self;
}
```

and copy the Fabric **Run Script** in build phases to your Today Extension target, and copy the Fabric entry from the info plist from the main application into your Today Extension's info plist

Comment: this is something that i forgot "copy the Fabric Run Script in build phases to your Today Extension target"

Answer (score 6):

Here is [**official** how-to](https://twittercommunity.com/t/integrate-fabric-crashlytics-with-ios-8-extension/28905) described how to use Crashlytics in iOS Extensions:

- Add this line to your `viewController`'s `initWithCoder` method `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])`
- Copy the "Fabric" Dictionary from your main app's Info.plist and paste into your extension's Info.plist.
- Copy/paste the Run Script Build Phase from your main app's target into your extension's Run Script Build Phase.

And... you good to go!

Comment: Another pitfall: You have to enable Answers in the Fabric dashboard for the extension. Don't know if that information is part of the above linked how-to, since I am greeted with "Sorry, you don't have access to that topic!" when I follow the link.

Answer (score 5):

Answer from maremmle works also if you want to add Crashlytics to share extensions on iOS 8.0+. Just remember to put`[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"apiKey"];` inside `init` method from your first ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all instructions, it works fine in my Share Extension.

I did notice that for my Share Extension, the Fabric Answers dashboard did **not** show actual data for:

1. Active Users
2. Median Total Time Spent in App per User

It does for the companion app.
So I was wondering how the Answers SDK would determine this. The most logical seems to monitor the UIApplication notifications.
Since the Lifecycle of an Extension is related to a ViewController, these UIApplication notifications are not posted. And hence Fabric doesn't know when the Extension is active.

So I implemented the following solution, which provides the above data in the Fabric Dashboard:

1. In 'viewDidLoad' of the Extensions main ViewController, post UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification which will trigger the start for Fabric.
2. Prior before closing the Extension (via [completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1411301-completerequest) or [cancelRequestWithError:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1412773-cancelrequestwitherror?language=objc)) post UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification. This will trigger the stop for Fabric.

Please note there is a delay between the action on device, and when the data becomes visible in the Dashboard.
Especially for **Active Users**. It takes around 20-30 seconds after the Extension is presented. But when the Extension is closed, it might take up to 5 *minutes* before the Active Users is decremented.