# How to use Crashlytics with iMessage Extensions?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, imessage-extension

I have an iMessage extension within my iOS app. Can Crashlytics capture its crashes?

I've tried adding the same `Fabric` entry from my main app's `Info.plist` into my iMessage extension's `Info.plist`, and adding the following to my `MSMessagesAppViewController` subclass (as recommended for [Today widget intregation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27146019/9636)):

```
- (instancetype _Nonnull)initWithNibName:(NSString * _Nullable)nibNameOrNil
                                  bundle:(NSBundle * _Nullable)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil
                           bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Start up Answers and Crashlytics
        [Fabric with:[NSArray<id> arrayWithObjects:
                      [Answers class],
                      [Crashlytics class],
                      nil]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But when I start iMessage and choose my iMessage extension, it just hangs on the previous screenshot. It never starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

We have experimental support for only Crashlytics on iMessage Extensions. To get things working:

1. Add your Fabric Run Script Build Phase to your extension's
   target. Copy and paste the one in your main app.
2. Add the Fabric and Crashlytics.framework to your extension's
   linked libraries
3. Add the `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("YourActualApiKey")` to your
   extension's view controller's  `initWithCodermethod`. If you don't
   have an `initWithCoder` method currently, it should look like this
   in the end:

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("yourApiKey")
   }

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153383/3975963

Comment: The link appears to be broken. Any update on iMessage extension support?

Comment: Modified my answer @nrj to provide more details.

Comment: Does is it also work for iMessage app (not extension)?

Comment: I haven't tested it explicitly, but would expect it to work. Again, I've done no testing on it yet.

Comment: I just finished adding this to our iMessage extension and it appears to work just fine. I would just note that now we use `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` rather than `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("yourApiKey")`.

Comment: Does `Crashlytics` call `CrashlyticsDelegate` when a previous crash occurred on an app extension? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61801745/9636