# Crashes from network extension not being reported

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a host app and network extension.  Crashes from the host app are being reported correctly, but nothing from the extension.

I'm calling

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

from `startTunnelWithOptions`, and then

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];
```

at the end of `startTunnelWithOptions`

I have the same Fabric entry in the info.plist and the same Fabric run script in build settings for the host app and the extension.  I'm running the app on device, not from Xcode.

What else could I be doing wrong?  I think I have covered all the bases in all the posts I have seen about this not working.

Comment: Thanks. You must pull the frameworks into each target. Also please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146019/how-to-use-crashlytics-with-ios-os-x-today-view-extensions

Comment: @ToddBurner I do have the frameworks in each target.  I'm not having any trouble importing or referencing them, so I presume they are being found.

I did see the post you referenced.  It contains several different approaches for starting up Crashlytics:
- Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("yourApiKey”)
- [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
- Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

I have tried them all, and none worked.

I am not able to access the thread on twittercommunity.com (“Sorry, you don’t have access to that topic!”) so I can’t see what wisdom it contains.

Comment: @ToddBurner Are you sure it works with a network extension specifically?  It seems that most everyone I see post about this who has gotten it working is doing some other kind of extension.