# Install Firebase / Crashlytics on iOS NEDNSProxyProvider Network extension

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, networkextension, nednsproxyprovider

I have an iOS app with a network extension and i'm trying to install Firebase/Crashlytics on both:

- Host app (**com.mycompany.appname**)
- NEDNSProxyProvider Network extension (**com.mycompany.appname.dnsproxy**)

I've installed Firebase on both targhet with Cocoapods and I've managed to configure successfully crashlytics on the host app, trigger a crash and seeing the crash in the firebase dashboard.

Then I've tried to enable crashlytics in the network extension first using these steps:

From [How to use Crashlytics with iOS / OS X today view extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146019/how-to-use-crashlytics-with-ios-os-x-today-view-extensions)

1. Copied the `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the host app to the network extension
2. Added the run script to the network extension targhet 
   [image]
3. IN the NEDNSProxyProvider subclass method `override func startProxy(options: [String: Any]? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {` I've added:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

Obviously, the extension crashes, but no reports are sent to the Firebase dashboard.

In the console I can see:

```
5.16.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.mimecast.SecurityAgent'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
```

That make sense, the targets have different bundleIDs.

So I've created another app in the Firebase project with the proper bundle id **com.mycompany.appname.dnsproxy**, I've downloaded the new `GoogleService-Info.plist`, run the app and followed the initial app setup, but apparently the network extension never calls the firebase backend, the induced crash isn't logged and I can't even finish the initial setup and i'm stuck in the `Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.` step.

Any idea? I can't see any strange Firebase log in the console or error.

Comment: Did you ever get this answered? I'm running into the same problem with my action extension.

Comment: I get same problem

Comment: @Andy nope sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the development document, add crashlytics and firebase domains to matchDomainsNoSearch property.